# How to make the select box value back to the default value

Tags: jquery

Here I want to make the select box value back to the default value.

```
 $(".reportingto").change(function() {
        var reportingtovalue = $(this).val();
        var reportingtoid=$(this).attr('id');
        $('select[id^="reportingto"]').each(function() {
            if(reportingtoid!==$(this).attr('id')&& reportingtovalue===$(this).val()){
                alert("Duplicate found");
                $(reportingtoid).val( $(reportingtoid).prop('defaultSelected') );
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the default value is the first/top one, this solution will work for you.

```
// Replace this
$(reportingtoid).val( $(reportingtoid).prop('defaultSelected') );

// With this
$('#'+reportingtoid).prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save the original value into a variable first.

for example:

```
 var origin = $(".reportingto").val();

 function reset() {
    $(".reportingto").val(origin);
 }

 $(".reportingto").change(function() {
    var reportingtovalue = $(this).val();
    var reportingtoid=$(this).attr('id');
    $('select[id^="reportingto"]').each(function() {
        if(reportingtoid!==$(this).attr('id')&& reportingtovalue===$(this).val()){
            alert("Duplicate found");
            $(reportingtoid).val( $(reportingtoid).prop('defaultSelected') );
        }

    });
```